# SweetAlert2 Vue Call a function in a tag HTML

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have this code:

html:

```html
<div>
    <p class="w-100" style="margin: 14px 10px;text-align:left;">Cambiar estado</p>
    <select id="status_action" value="" class="swal2-input">
        <option value="" class="optionStatus">Selecciona un estado</option>
        <option value = "Aprobado" class="optionStatus" id="statusAprobado" onclick = "${this.optionValue = "Aprobado"}">Aprobado</option>
        <option value = "Por-documentar" class="optionStatus" id="statusDocumentar" onclick = "${this.optionValue = "Por-documentar"}">Por documentar</option>
        <option value = "Descartado" class="optionStatus" id="statusDescartado" onclick = "${this.optionValue = "Descartado"}">Descartado</option>
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="reviewersDiv" style="display: none;">
    <p class="w-100" style="margin: 14px 10px;text-align:left;">Revisores</p>
    <select id="reviewer_id" value="" class="swal2-input"  onchange="${this.settingEvents()}">
    <option value="">Selecciona un revisor</option>                 
    ${this.usersReviewer.map(
        (user) => (
            `<option value="${user.id}">
                ${user.name + " - " + user.role_user[0].area_project_name}
            </option>`
        )
    )}
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm changing the value of my variable optionvalue depending of the option that I click, then validate it to show the other div that I have:

```js
if (this.optionValue.value === "Por-documentar") {
    reviewersDiv.style.display = "block";
} else {
    reviewersDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

but it nevers change the value of the variable, how can I do?

Comment: Can you post also the content of the function ```toggleReviewersDiv()``` ?

Comment: I change the code, please give me a help :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't still quite understand your problem. If you can make an playground even just static data like [this one](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/abXdJBY) or show the output you want to achieve, maybe I can help you in some way.